# React Js Event handling in Mapped object

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React js and I cannot get the following code to work, I am trying to build a calculator but when I put the onClick event handler on mapped objects they do not work. Any help would be appreciated

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{
  
constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
    initialVal:'',
    formula:'33',
    buttons:buttons
  }
  this.clearMem = this.clearMem.bind(this)
  this.addToFormula = this.addToFormula.bind(this)

}
componentDidMount = () =>{
  console.log("Component Mounted!!")
}
clearMem = () => {
  console.log("clearmem")
    this.setState({formula:'0'})
  }

addToFormula = (e) => {
  console.log(e)
  this.setState({formula:'9999'})

}

render(){



       const {formula} = this.state;
       return (
         <div className="calculator-wrapper">
           <div className="display">{formula}</div>
           {
             this.state.buttons.map(function(button){
                  if (button.id==="AC"){
                   return <Button
                           onClick = {this.clearMem}
                           key={button.id}
                           value={button.value}
                           className="number-button"/>

                }  else if (button.id === '-'){  return  <Button
                           key={button.id}
                           value={button.value}
                           className="number-button"
                           />
                }  else if (button.id === '+'){  return  <Button
                           key={button.id}
                           value={button.value}
                           className="number-button"
                           />
                }  else if (button.id === '/'){  return  <Button
                           key={button.id}
                           value={button.value}
                           className="number-button"
                           />
                }  else if (button.id === '*'){  return  <Button
                           key={button.id}
                           value={button.value}
                           className="number-button"
                           />
                }  else if (button.id === '='){  return  <Button
                           key={button.id}
                           value={button.value}
                           className="number-button"
                           />
                }  else if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(button.id))){  return <Button
                           key={button.id}
                           value={button.value}
                           className="number-button"
                           onClick = {this.addToFormula}
                           />
                }

              },this)
           }




         </div>

       )
}
}
```

I am trying to eventually make it so that when I press the "AC" button the formula turns to zero. But no onClick event handler works for any of the mapped objects
Any help would be tremendous. Thank you

Comment: "when I put the onClick event handler on mapped objects they do not work" care to expand on what this means? What isn't working? Does `Button` pass `onClick` prop to element? Are there any errors? `clearMem` and `addToFormula` are arrow functions so they don't need to be bound in the constructor. Also, specifying what the `this` is in the mapping callback isn't really necessary.

Comment: No, the button component does not pass prop to element. I get no errors. I am learning React so thanks for the tip on not needing to bind arrow functions. I tried giving the Child Componen Button an "onClick" even handler but when I click on the rendered button element nothing happens.

Comment: Ok, sounds like the button isn't doing anything with that prop. Can you update your question to include the `Button` component code?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Calculator extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      initialVal:'',
      formula:'33',
      buttons:[{"id":"AC", "value":"AC"},{"id":"+","value":"+"},{"id":"-","value":"-"},{"id":"/","value":"/"},{"id":"*","value":"*"},{"id":"=","value":"="}]
      }
      this.clearMem = this.clearMem.bind(this)
      this.addToFormula = this.addToFormula.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount = () =>{
      console.log("Component Mounted!!")
    }
    clearMem = () => {
      console.log("clearmem")
      this.setState({formula:'0'})
    }

    addToFormula = (e) => {
      console.log(e)
      this.setState({formula:'9999'})
    }

render(){
    const {formula} = this.state;
    return (
     <div className="calculator-wrapper">
       <div className="display">{formula}</div>
       {
         this.state.buttons.map(function(button){
              if (button.id==="AC"){
               return <Button
                       handleClick = {this.clearMem}
                       key={button.id}
                       value={button.value}
                       className="number-button"/>

            }  else if (button.id === '-'){  return  <Button
                       key={button.id}
                       value={button.value}
                       className="number-button"
                       />
            }  else if (button.id === '+'){  return  <Button
                       key={button.id}
                       value={button.value}
                       className="number-button"
                       />
            }  else if (button.id === '/'){  return  <Button
                       key={button.id}
                       value={button.value}
                       className="number-button"
                       />
            }  else if (button.id === '*'){  return  <Button
                       key={button.id}
                       value={button.value}
                       className="number-button"
                       />
            }  else if (button.id === '='){  return  <Button
                       key={button.id}
                       value={button.value}
                       className="number-button"
                       />
            }  else if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(button.id))){  return <Button
                       key={button.id}
                       value={button.value}
                       className="number-button"
                       onClick = {this.addToFormula}
                       />
            }
          },this)
       }
     </div>
    )
  }
}


import React from 'react';

const Button = (props) => (
    <button
        id={props.id}
        onClick={props.handleClick}>{props.value} 
    </button>
)

export default Button
```

Comment: I did this and it works this way. Thank you. Not seen in my code is the Button component, would there be any way to make my original idea work,  That is passing an event handler to child components, this would seem like a useful feature and I would love to know how to do this for future projects. Thanks

Comment: I have updated the code will this be helpful. Instead of adding onclick you need to provide some prop name to the event and call it in Button Component.